# how do i normalize pixels faster between 0 and 26

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a vector with about 150528 pixels.

```
img1 = image.load_img(path = "image.jpg", target_size = (224, 224, 3))

img1_pixel_array = image.img_to_array(img = img1, dtype = np.uint8)

a = img1_pixel_array.reshape(150528,)
```

I normalizing between 0 and 26 for this data.

```
list = []
for i in a:
    z = (i - min(a)) / (max(a) - min(a)) * 26
    list.append(z)
```

The problem is that only 1000 pixels are processed in 40 seconds.
My question is how do I normalize this data between 0 and 26 faster.

Comment: 1. Convert a to float. z=(a-min(a))/(max(a)-min(a))*26, convert z to uint8

Comment: **use numpy**, do it on the **entire** array, not individual elements... DO NOT use plain python lists, DO NOT reshape to make the whole thing flat.

Comment: When you do `min(a)`, you loop over the whole array. Because you do this within a loop over the whole array, you have created an O(n^2) algorithm: grow the array 10x, the algorithm takes 100x as long to run. This is obviously very inefficient. You only need to compute `min(a)` (and `max(a)`) once.

Comment: I tried this before you wrote it, and that's how it worked. I assigned the maximum and minimum values ​​to the variables. Thanks for your help @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 1):

If seems that you are recomputing the minimum (twice) and maximum of `a` on every iteration. This does not sound like a good idea.

You'd better precompute the scaling coefficients A and B such that z = A i + B.

Comment: Could you show this with codes?

Comment: @Joseph: sorry, no.